# bulk email using send grid in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, smtp, sendgrid, bulk-email

***Context:***

I need to send bulk-email using send grid in a rails app.
I will be sending emails to maybe around 300 subscribers.
I have read that it can be accomplished using

```
headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = { :to => array_of_recipients }.to_json
```

I have tried following that.

The following is my ActionMailer:

```
class NewJobMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def new_job_post(subscribers)
    @greeting = "Hi"
    headers['X-SMTPAPI'] = { :to => subscribers.to_a }.to_json
    mail(
    :to => "this.will@be.ignored.com",
    :subject => "New Job Posted!"
    )

  end

end
```

I call this mailer method from a controller

```
..
   @subscribers = Subscriber.where(activated: true)
   NewJobMailer.new_job_post(@subscribers).deliver
..
```

The config for send-grid is specified in the config/production.rb file and is correct, since I am able to send out account activation emails.

***Problem:***

The app works fine without crashing anywhere, but the emails are not being sent out.
I am guessing the headers config is not being passed along ?
How can I correct this ?

***UPDATE:***

I checked for email activity in the send grid dashboard.
Here is a snapshot of one of the dropped emails:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are grabbing an array of ActiveRecord objects with

```
@subscribers = Subscriber.where(activated: true)
```

and passing that into the smtpapi header. You need to pull out the email addresses of those ActiveRecord objects.

Depending on what you called the `email` field, this can be done with

```
headers['X-SMTPAPI'] = { :to => subscribers.map(&:email) }.to_json
```